# Octave - undefined

Tags: octave

I got a problem with running Octave function (ODE), I've tried already present solutions for this problem but nothing is working

The error is:

> error: 'formStiffness3Dframe' undefined near line 31 column 13

```
% clear memory
clear all
% E; modulus of elasticity
% I: second moment of area
% L: length of bar
E=210e6; A=0.02;
Iy=10e-5; Iz=20e-5; J=5e-5; G=84e6;
% generation of coordinates and connectivities
nodeCoordinates=[0 0 0; 3 0 0; 0 0 -3; 0 -4 0];
xx=nodeCoordinates(:,1);
yy=nodeCoordinates(:,2);
zz=nodeCoordinates(:,3);
elementNodes=[1 2;1 3;1 4];
numberNodes=size(nodeCoordinates,1);
numberElements=size(elementNodes,1);
% for structure:
% displacements: displacement vector
% force : force vector
% stiffness: stiffness matrix
% GDof: global number of degrees of freedom
GDof=6*numberNodes;
U=zeros(GDof,1);
force=zeros(GDof,1);
stiffness=zeros(GDof,GDof);
%force vector
force(1)=-10;
force(3)=20;
% stiffness matrix
[stiffness]=formStiffness3Dframe(GDof,numberElements,elementNodes,numberNodes,nodeCoordinates,E,A,Iz,Iy,G,J);
```

Comment: That seems to be a function from this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=skdFXpM0XycC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=formStiffness3Dframe&source=bl&ots=Xl51jWcoPB&sig=ACfU3U1ltgOEZYzVl4H7AApjxlTciFjsiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjg5_F_LTqAhUQV80KHf94CgIQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=formStiffness3Dframe&f=false — Since it’s not part of any official Octave packages, you need to manually copy the function M-file to somewhere on your Octave path.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Looking at the link @Cris provided, the listing for the `formStiffness3Dframe` function is on the next page of the book after the code you included in your question...